# How to make all my views as navigationController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My app contains many views, all the views should be a UINavigationViewcontroller.
I know the code to use a navigation page.

To make it in all the views I should make changes in my AppDelegate, could anyone please help with the code.

Comment: Can you post your actual code? What have you tried? What error XCode gives you?

Comment: What I am saying is that, While starting a new project, it is loaded with an .xib file for user interface. By default it is an UIViewController, I want to make it as UINavigationController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you are new in iOS and want to try the NavigationController, start with the storyboard and a good tutorial. 
The storyboard will handle most of the work about your navigationController.

I recommend this tutorial using storyboard : [NavigationController Storyboard](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/)

This one is if you don't use storyboard and do it programmatically using iOS 4/5 : [NavigationController iOS4/5](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews)

This tutorial teach you how to add with interface builder a navigation controller : [Navigation Controller with interface builder](http://www.ralfebert.de/archive/ios/tutorial_iosdev/navigationcontroller/)

Comment: Actually, I have worked in storyBoard well and good, Now I want to start creating with Interface Builder as I am creating an app for iOS4. Do U have any tutorial for this

Comment: But, I want to use interface Builder

Comment: Edited again with a tutorial for adding navController with interface builder

Comment: Could U find anything using fully programming

Comment: It's not that easy to find a good tutorial only programming a navigationController since the correct way is by using it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42182/discussion-between-chandru-and-pull)